# div and its content are not showing in page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to learn how to create a testimonials part on my page and somehow none of its contexts are showing up, no mater what I write.

I also tried to create an empty project with nothing inside, import all the text and still not show up. showing nothing but a blank page.

I'm new to HTML so am I doing something wrong?

So this is my `index.html` page

```html
<body>

  <div class="demo">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div id="testimonial-slider" class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="testimonial">
              <div class="pic">
                <img src="images/img-1.jpg">
              </div>
              <h3 class="title">Williamson</h3>
              <span class="post">Web Developer</span>
              <p class="description">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A accusantium ad asperiores at atque culpa
                dolores eaque fugiat hic illo ipsam ipsum minima modi necessitatibus nemo officia, omnis perferendis
                placeat sit vitae, consectetur adipisicing elit ipsam.
              </p>

              awdawdaw
              daw
              dawdaw
              d
            </div>
            <div class="testimonial">
              <div class="pic">
                <img src="images/img-2.jpg">
              </div>
              <h3 class="title">Kristina</h3>
              <span class="post">Web Designer</span>
              <p class="description">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A accusantium ad asperiores at atque culpa
                dolores eaque fugiat hic illo ipsam ipsum minima modi necessitatibus nemo officia, omnis perferendis
                placeat sit vitae, consectetur adipisicing elit ipsam.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testimonial-slider").owlCarousel({
      items: 1,
      itemsDesktop: [1000, 1],
      itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 1],
      itemsTablet: [768, 1],
      pagination: true,
      transitionStyle: "backSlide",
      autoPlay: true
    });
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js">
</script>
```

`style.css` is this

```css
.demo {
  background: #3d3d3d;
}

.testimonial {
  padding: 35px 50px;
  margin: 0 20px 30px;
  border-radius: 0 70px 0 70px;
  border: 5px solid #ffc33c;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.testimonial .pic {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.testimonial .pic img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.testimonial .title {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 7px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ffc33c;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.testimonial .post {
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.testimonial .description {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span {
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page.active span {
  background: #ffc33c;
}
```

Comment: Change the order of the script tags. First jQuery, then owl, then your script.

Comment: jQuery 1.12 is unsupported. You should upgrade to a current version.

Comment: how can i do that? whats the newest version of jquery?

Comment: Take a look here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries#jquery but always make sure that your code still works when using a newer version maybe they made changes that break your code!

Comment: Or download it and use it inside your project https://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you did not put the `script` tags inside the `body` also you need to lead libraries like jQuery before executing your own code:

```css
.demo {
  background: #3d3d3d;
}

.testimonial {
  padding: 35px 50px;
  margin: 0 20px 30px;
  border-radius: 0 70px 0 70px;
  border: 5px solid #ffc33c;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.testimonial .pic {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.testimonial .pic img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.testimonial .title {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 7px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ffc33c;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.testimonial .post {
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.testimonial .description {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span {
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page.active span {
  background: #ffc33c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="demo">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div id="testimonial-slider" class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="testimonial">
              <div class="pic">
                <img src="images/img-1.jpg">
              </div>
              <h3 class="title">Williamson</h3>
              <span class="post">Web Developer</span>
              <p class="description">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A accusantium ad asperiores at atque culpa dolores eaque fugiat hic illo ipsam ipsum minima modi necessitatibus nemo officia, omnis perferendis placeat sit vitae, consectetur adipisicing elit ipsam.
              </p>

              awdawdaw daw dawdaw d
            </div>
            <div class="testimonial">
              <div class="pic">
                <img src="images/img-2.jpg">
              </div>
              <h3 class="title">Kristina</h3>
              <span class="post">Web Designer</span>
              <p class="description">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A accusantium ad asperiores at atque culpa dolores eaque fugiat hic illo ipsam ipsum minima modi necessitatibus nemo officia, omnis perferendis placeat sit vitae, consectetur adipisicing elit ipsam.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#testimonial-slider").owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        itemsDesktop: [1000, 1],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 1],
        itemsTablet: [768, 1],
        pagination: true,
        transitionStyle: "backSlide",
        autoPlay: true
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I moved the `script` tags inside the `body` and changed the order of the `script` tags so that the JavaScript gets loaded and executed in the correct order.

Comment: thank you, but can you also help me with understanding something? somehow the script wont show the panel in the center. where in the style says to have it on the left but not in center? even if I put ``left:50%`` it wont change

Comment: Did you use `left` without `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;`? If you cannot find a solution please provide working code via https://codesandbox.io/ or so or consider opening a new question

Answer (score 0):

You should import your libraries before using them. Just change the order of `<script>` tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testimonial-slider").owlCarousel({
        items:1,
        itemsDesktop:[1000,1],
        itemsDesktopSmall:[979,1],
        itemsTablet:[768,1],
        pagination:true,
        transitionStyle:"backSlide",
        autoPlay:true
    });
});</script>
```